# Add MySQL to my Makefile gives problems

Tags: mysql, c, makefile

I have a problem with my C project built under Debian Jessie. After doing some stuffs now I need to work with MySQL so i download the library and try to update my Makefile.

This is my **Makefile** right now

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra 
LDFLAGS = -lbluetooth -lpthread -lmysqlclient
LFLAGS = -lm
INC = -I/usr/include/mysql

SOURCES = stb.c btscan.c and.c gima.c database.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = stb

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

stb.o: btscan.h and.h gima.h database.h

btscan.o: btscan.h

and.o: and.h

gima.o: gima.h

database.o: database.h

clean:
    @rm -f *.o *.out stb
```

and this is the files where I want to use the library

**stb.c**

```
    #include "btscan.h"
    #include "and.h"
    #include "gima.h"
    #include "database.h"

    struct device* bt_devices; 
    struct device* ble_devices;     

    int main(void) {

        //-------------------------------- DATABASE CONNECTION ----------------

        //MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

....... }
```

and finally **database.h**

```
#ifndef _DATABASE_H
#define _DATABASE_H

#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#endif
```

When I try to make i receive "Fatal error : my_global.h No such file or directory". However if i try MySQL on a single test file and compiling it with

```
gcc -o test test.c -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

it works. Where I made a mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you run `make` after cleaning, what is the output? What are the commands `make` call doing? Please post that output. In fact, please post the *full* output of building the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd shown us the output of the compiler, or examine it yourself, you'll immediately see that what you're running on the command line is not the same at all as what make is running: in particular make is not adding the `-I/usr/include/mysql` flag to the command line.

That's because in your makefile you set:

```
INC = -I/usr/include/mysql
```

but nowhere in your makefile (as you've shown it) is the variable `INC` actually used, so this is essentially a no-op.

Since you're using the standard GNU make compilation rules, you should be setting standard GNU make variables:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/mysql
```